# Exact places of articulation of Korean coronal consonants

Tags: pronunciation

What are the exact places of articulation of Korean coronal consonants, e.g. ㄴ, ㄷ, ㄸ, ㄹ, ㅅ, ㅆ, ㅌ?

The passive articulators are **dental**, **alveolar**, or **postalveolar**, and the active articulators are **apical** or **laminal**. What are the exact combinations for the consonants above?

In my pronunciation, all stops (ㄴ, ㄷ, ㄸ, ㅌ) are lamino-postalveolar. What's interesting is how I discriminate ㅅ and ㅆ. My ㅅ is apico-alveolar [s̺], and my ㅆ is lamino-dental [θ̻], if not as non-sibilant as English [θ]. For ㄹ, it is apico-postalveolar (or in other words, apical retroflex), for both central version ([ɽ̺]) and lateral version ([ɭ̺]).

I doubt every Korean has the same articulations, but was there a study on this?

Comment: I'm guessing that what you're asking might be about `조음 위치`(Place of articulation) in `한국어 음운론`(Korean phonology) which I remember was taught in high school in South Korea. Although I don't have much knowledge on this subject there could be someone else well versed in this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been a few. The *Sounds of Korean* (2003) has a [section devoted to each of the consonants](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vTuB12nR3qEC&pg=PA29#v=onepage&q&f=false).

[Ko (2013)](http://www.ling.hawaii.edu/graduate/Dissertations/InsungKoFinal.pdf) gives a good rundown of the literature prior, and has an emphasis on natives vs learners, useful for pedagogues. There has also been [stroboscopic-cine MRI](https://www.karger.com/Article/Abstract/84160) done.

To summarise then, the vast majority of these consonants are consistently **laminal** (with the blade), with the exception of the pronunciations of ㄹ. [These](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vTuB12nR3qEC&pg=PA53):

> involve the **tip and/or blade** of the tongue making contact with the dental ridge and/or the upper front teeth [...]